Is there an utility to keep certain apps from closing ? (with or without root)
Any external clock alarm app I have tried on my Android 11 phone shuts down automatically at a certain period of time (some hours), so I cannot use it as an alarm clock.
I have tried to set those apps not battery optimized, of course, with no luck.
Can it be achieved with some utility ? I have tried "auto memory manager" but it crashes at startup, and it's too old. Maybe with Tasker ? how ?...
Some apps like termux or IRC for Android already implement it but e.g. Alarm clock for Heavy Sleepers shuts down, and I love this app because you can snooze it by turning upside down the phone, and also it can play radio streams...

I use AMDroid without any issue, but in regards to your question, does locking the app not work?

What phone model do you use? Some phone manufacturer are known for modifying Android that it performs extreme aggressive battery saving (means app killing). https://dontkillmyapp.com

@Arctiic Yes, in some models it works (MI MIX 2 with crDroid) bot not in others like the my oldie Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016, SM-A510f) that I use to wake up.... It seems that I have found a fix using an app (not in the Play store) called Memory Locker (requires root) !

There is an option by the magisk module, I mentioned it here, if there are any further questions I will be happy to help.
